# T-SQL - Update Table with data from the same table - Ambiguous table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble understanding why this query is not working. I get a message

> The table '#PriceChanges' is ambiguous

The first mention of #PriceChanges is underlined

```
UPDATE #PriceChanges
SET MaxQty = MIN(ISNULL(PT.MinQty, 100000000))
FROM #PriceChanges P
LEFT JOIN #PriceChanges PT ON P.ChangeType = PT.ChangeType
                           AND P.ItemNo = PT.ItemNo
                           AND P.MinQty < PT.MinQty
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is setting the MAX quantity of a given line to the next MIN quantity found in the same table. If there's none found, then just make it a ridiculously high number (100,000,000)

The end result should look like something like this

```
MinQty  MaxQty
-----------------
   0          20
  20          50
  50         100
 100   100000000
```

Comment: MIN is aggregate function. can not use in the update statement. use CTE

Comment: I find it strange that you are updating something called "max" to the min of a bunch of min values.  Seems weird.

Comment: I'm updating the MAX quantity in the row with the next minimum quantity found. So if i want to do a price check later, i can do WHERE Quantity BETWEEN MinQty AND MaxQty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ambiguity arises because the `FROM` clause of the `UPDATE` refers to the `#PriceChanges` table twice, so there is no way for SQL Server to know which of the two you intend to update. To resolve the ambiguity, instead of writing `UPDATE #PriceChanges`, use `UPDATE P` or `UPDATE PT`. Here's a trivial example:

```
create table #Test (id int, datum char(1));
insert #Test values (1, ' '), (2, ' ');

-- ERROR: The table '#Test' is ambiguous.
update #Test set datum = 'X' from #Test T1 inner join #Test T2 on T1.id = T2.id + 1;

-- CORRECT: Use the appropriate table alias to indicate which instance of #Test you want to update.
update T1 set datum = 'X' from #Test T1 inner join #Test T2 on T1.id = T2.id + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating an intermediary table worked, I still wonder why this couldn't all be put into a single update

```
SELECT P.ChangeType, P.ItemNo, P.MinQty, MIN(PT.MinQty) AS MaxQty
INTO #MaxQty
FROM #PriceChanges P
LEFT JOIN #PriceChanges PT
    ON P.ChangeType = PT.ChangeType
    AND P.ItemNo = PT.ItemNo
    AND P.MinQty < PT.MinQty
GROUP BY P.ChangeType, P.ItemNo, P.MinQty

UPDATE #PriceChanges 
SET MaxQty = ISNULL(PM.MaxQty, 100000000)
FROM #PriceChanges P
LEFT JOIN #MaxQty PM
    ON P.ChangeType = PM.ChangeType
    AND P.ItemNo = PM.ItemNo
    AND P.MinQty = PM.MinQty
```

Answer (score -1):

I see no use for `ISNULL(PT.MinQty, 100000000)`.  `MIN()` ignores `NULL` values.  And you don't need a self join.  An updatable CTE or subquery works:

```
UPDATE pc
    SET MaxQty = min_minqty
FROM (SELECT pc.*, MIN(pc.MinQty) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNo, ChangeType) as min_minqty
      FROM #PriceChanges pc 
     ) pc
WHERE pc.MaxQty <> min_minqty;
```

EDIT:

You appear to want:

```
with pc as (
      select pc.*,
             lead(pc.MinQty) over (order by pc.MinQty) as next_MinQty
      from #PriceChanges pc
     )
update pc
    set MaxQty = next_MinQty;
```

Comment: This sets the maxQty to the second lowest minQty found. look at the little table to see the expected result. thanks anyway